# Mark class field

Tags: php, reflection

I am looking for a way to mark a field, and use that mark later for different operation on the object.

For example, serialize object without the marked fields:

```
class A(){
   public $field1;

   //@dont_serialize
   public $field2;
} 

$obj = new A();
$obj->field1 = "important data";
$obj->field2 = "not important data";

function MySerialize($obj){
  $arr = (array) $obj;
  $new_arr = array();   
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      if (THIS FEILD IS NOT MARKED AS @dont_serialize)
      {
        $new_arr[$key] = $value
      }
  }
  return serialize($new_arr);
}
```

How can I implement MySerialize() that will not serialize marked fields ?

Comment: Without reflection (which would be a serious hack) you probably want to build an array of fields to serialize or not serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go forward with reflection API you should "mark" your fields with "appropriate"(formatted) comment. 
Here is working solution using `ReflectionClass` class, `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment`, `ReflectionProperty::getName` and `ReflectionProperty::getValue` methods:

```
class A {

    public $field1;
    public $field2;

    /**
     * @dont_serialize
     */
    public $field3;

}

$obj = new A();
$obj->field1 = "important data";
$obj->field2 = "needed data";
$obj->field3 = "not important data";

function MySerialize($obj) {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
    $props = $reflector->getProperties();
    $new_arr = [];

    foreach ($props as $property) {
        if (strpos($property->getDocComment(), "@dont_serialize") === false) {
            $new_arr[$property->getName()] = $property->getValue($obj);
        }
    }
    return serialize($new_arr);
}

print_r(MySerialize($obj));
```

The output:

```
"a:2:{s:6:"field1";s:14:"important data";s:6:"field2";s:11:"needed data";}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your annotation and process it, good example is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742661/3354887

Also there is a docblock parser: https://github.com/doctrine/annotations

Answer (score 0):

Just for the serialize purpose, there is a better approach, instead of marking the properties and use reflection.

There are, magic functions __sleep(), __wakeup()... allowing to change the fields that will be serialized with serialize() function for details look at 
http://php.net/language.oop5.magic